# Ob_flush without discarding buffer

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a PHP script that takes a few minutes to finish processing. While the page is still loading, I want to show part of the PHP output as it becomes available, which can be done using `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()`.

After the entire script has finish executing, I want to save all the PHP output right from the start into a HTML file. This can be done using `ob_start()` and `file_put_contents("log.html", ob_get_contents());`

**Problem:** However, because we are calling `ob_flush()` along the way, the final file that gets saved with `file_put_contents()` appears to be separated into different files. I suspect this has to do with the buffer being cleared by the `ob_start()` calls before `file_put_contents()` is called, but why did it not just save the output between the final `ob_flush()` and `file_put_contents()` to the file, but instead saves several different files? *(I may be wrong, the seperate partial files may be due to partial execution of the script)*

In other words, how do I show PHP output as a long script executes, and still save all the PHP output to a single HTML file?

**PHP Code**

```
// Start the buffering
ob_start();

......

ob_flush();

......

ob_flush();

......

file_put_contents("log.html", ob_get_contents());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of ways I can think of:

1. Keep a variable (called something like $content), and append the current buffer every time you call ob_flush():

   ```
   $content = '';
   ...
   $content .= ob_get_contents();
   ob_flush();
   ...
   $content .= ob_get_contents();
   ob_flush();
   ...
   file_put_contents('log.html', $content . ob_get_contents());
   ob_flush();
   ```
2. Use fopen():

   ```
   $fp = fopen('log.html', 'w+');
   ...
   fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
   ob_flush();
   ...
   fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
   ob_flush();
   ...
   fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
   fclose($fp);
   ob_flush();
   ```

Comment: Why did you do `file_put_contents('log.html', $content . ob_get_contents());` instead of `file_put_contents('log.html', $content);

Comment: You still have some content in the final buffer.  Alternatively, you could put "$content .= ob_get_contents();" on the line before if you do "file_put_contents('log.html', $content);"

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `ob_get_contents()` along the way, save it to a variable and then into the file and the outputstream...

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the buffer contents, and store it in a a variable by calling [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-get-contents.php).

Have you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)?